# How can I compute the momentum of a specific quantum particle in a quantum many-body system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, momentum, many-body

I'm not sure if this question even makes sense in a quantum mechanical context, but I was wondering how does one compute the observed momentum of a specific quantum particle in a quantum many-body system?

What about the kinetic energy and how does it relate to the kinetic energy of the entire system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1|}$The state of a quantum $n$-body system is a sum of tensor products of states of the individual particles: $$\ket\psi=\sum_i\ket{\phi_{i1}}\otimes\cdots\otimes\ket{\phi_{in}}$$

Where each $\ket{\phi_{ij}}\in\mathcal H_j$ and $\mathcal H_j$ is the Hilbert space describing the $j$th particle. The state of the whole system $\ket\psi\in\mathcal H$ lives in the Hilbert space $\mathcal H=\mathcal H_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\mathcal H_n.$ In the example of two particles in 1D space, $\mathcal H_1=\mathcal H_2=L^2(\mathbb R),\mathcal H=L^2(\mathbb R^2),$ and the wavefunction $\psi(x,y)$ of the two-body system decomposes as $\psi(x,y)=\sum_i\phi_{i1}(x)\phi_{i2}(y),$ where the $\phi_{i1}(x)$ are wavefunctions for the first particle and similarly for $\phi_{i2}(y).$ You could also choose a different basis for either particle; e.g. you could write all the $\phi_{i2}$ in the momentum basis, and then the combined wavefunction would be $\psi(x,p_y).$

Any operator on a single-particle Hilbert space, say $A:\mathcal H_k\to\mathcal H_k$ can be lifted to act on the whole of $\mathcal H$ by tensoring it with a bunch of identity operators, one for each of the other Hilbert spaces: $\tilde A=\mathbb I\otimes\cdots\otimes A\otimes\cdots\otimes\mathbb I.$ The lifted operator $\tilde A$ acts on a tensor product by applying $A$ to the appropriate factor. $$\tilde A\ket\psi=\sum_i\ket{\phi_{i1}}\otimes\cdots\otimes A\ket{\psi_{ik}}\otimes\cdots\otimes\ket{\phi_{in}}$$

In your case, if you can construct a momentum observable for your single-particle space, then you can lift that into an observable that acts on the many-body space and measures the momentum of the specified particle. In the two-body example, the momentum operator for the first particle is $\hat p_1=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}.$ Lifting it and applying it to the two-particle state gives $\hat p_1\psi(x,y)=\sum_i(\hat p_1\phi_{i1}(x))\phi_{i2}(y)=-i\hbar\sum_i\left(\frac{d\phi_{i1}(x)}{dx}\right)\phi_{i2}(y)=-i\hbar\frac{\partial\psi(x,y)}{\partial x}$ (it is common to use the same symbol for the single-particle and lifted operators). The way you compute e.g. expectation values is the same as always, just with a slightly different expansion: $$\langle\hat p_1\rangle=\bra\psi\hat p_1\ket\psi=-i\hbar\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\psi^*(x,y)\frac\partial{\partial x}\psi(x,y)\;dx\,dy.$$

You can do the same thing with the kinetic energy operators $\hat T_k=\frac1{2m_k}\hat p_k^2.$ They lift to the many-body Hilbert space without fuss and let you extract the kinetic energy associated to any one particle. The kinetic energy operator of the whole system can be *defined* as the sum of the kinetic energy operators: $\hat T=\hat T_1+\cdots+\hat T_n.$

If you would further like to compute the whole probability *distribution* of an observable, you can start with an eigenbasis $A\ket{a_\ell}=a_\ell\ket{a_\ell}$ for the single-particle operator. Then you can construct a projection operator $\hat P=\ket{a_\ell}\bra{a_\ell}$ such that $\langle\hat P\rangle=\bra\psi\hat P\ket\psi$ gives the probability (density) of measuring the observable $A$ to be $a_\ell$ (in the single-particle Hilbert space). Finally, you can lift $\hat P$ to the many-body Hilbert space and use it to compute probabilities there, too.

Comment: You nowhere mention that all quantum mechanical calculations are probabilistic, that one needs many measurement to check the calculation. One cannot predict the momentum of a single particle, only  the probability that the momentum has  a given value.

Comment: Very comprehensive, thank you.